# Best format for Pandas serialization on disk

Tags: pandas

For my workload, I need to serialize on disk Pandas dataframe (Text +Datas) with a size of 5Go per Dataframe.
Came across various solutions:

```
HDF5   : Issues with string
Feather: not stable
CSV: Ok, but large file size.
pickle : Ok, cross-platform, can we do better ?
gzip : Same than CSV (slow for read access).
SFrame:  Good, but not maintained anymore.
```

Just wondering any alternative solution to pickle to store string Dataframe on disk ?

Comment: In the future you can look forward to parquet: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/outlook-for-2017/

Comment: Isn't parquet have some platform restrictions ?

Answer (score 0):

parquet is the best format because this is used for Big tech company storing petabytes of data....

Answer (score -1):

I suggest reading this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d

The author concludes that `feather` is the most efficient serialization. However, it would not suitable for long-term storage - which is likely to be `CSV` (form long-term).